# Can't get custom options on product edit screen

Tags: event-observer, custom-options, magento-ce

For some reason the below code when attached to an observer ( doesn't let me display the custom options on the configure screen, the info_buyRequest returned by the configure page code just has the current qty and original qty, no custom options.

**Observers**

```
        <sales_quote_add_item> (processOptions)
        <checkout_cart_product_add_after> (addKeepsakes)
```

**Observer Code**

```
        public function addKeepsakes($observer){
        $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
        $cart->init();

        if( Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('keepsake') == 'yes' ){
            $keepsakesPrice = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('finalprice_keeps');
            $ksPrice = $keepsakesPrice / Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('keepsake-qty');

            $additionalOptions = array(
                        'options' => array(
                             'label' => 'Finish',
                             'value' => Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('keepsake-finish')
                        ),
                        array(
                             'label' => 'Size',
                             'value' => Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('keepsake-size')
                        ),
                        array(
                             'label' => 'Product',
                             'value' => $observer->getProduct()->getName()
                        )
                    );

            $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->addProduct( Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(37), Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('keepsake-qty') )->setCustomPrice($ksPrice)->setOriginalCustomPrice($ksPrice);
            $quote->addOption(new Varien_Object(
                        array(
                            'product' => $quote->getProduct(),
                            'code' => 'additional_options',
                            'value' => serialize($additionalOptions)
                        )
                    ));

            if ($additionalOptions = $quote->getOptionByCode('additional_options')) {
                $orderItem = $quote;
                $options = $orderItem->getProductOptions();
                $options['additional_options'] = unserialize($additionalOptions->getValue());
                $orderItem->setProductOptions($options);
            }

        }

        $cart->getQuote()->setData('updated', true);
        $cart->save();
    }

    public function salesConvertQuoteItemToOrderItem($observer) {

        $quoteItem = $observer->getItem();
        if ($additionalOptions = $quoteItem->getOptionByCode('additional_options')) {
            $orderItem = $observer->getOrderItem();
            $options = $orderItem->getProductOptions();
            $options['additional_options'] = unserialize($additionalOptions->getValue());
            $orderItem->setProductOptions($options);
        }
    }
```

**Configure Page Code**

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
        // Loop through all items in the cart
        $items =  $session->getQuote()->getItemsCollection()->getItems();   
        $options=array();
        $result=array();

        foreach( $items as $item )
        {   
            if ($item->getId() == $this->getRequest()->getParam('id') &&
                $item->getProductId()== $_product->getId() && 
                Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRequestedActionName() == 'configure') 
            {
                $result = $item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($item->getProduct());
                var_dump($item->getBuyRequest());
                if (!empty($result)) $options=$result['info_buyRequest'];
                break;
            }
        }
```

The weird thing is I have this function which works fine, and the configure page code will retrieve the options that are set by this:

```
       public function processOptions( $observer ) {

        // Save the cart, or else does not run if cart is empty initially
        $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
        $cart->init();

        // Get the quote object
        $quote_item = $observer->getQuoteItem();

        // Get attribute set model.
        $model = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_set');

        // Get product
        $product = $quote_item->getProduct();

        // Get attribute set id.
        $attributeSetId = $product->getAttributeSetId();
        $attributeSet = $model->load($attributeSetId);

        // This is attribute set name.
        $attributeSetName = $attributeSet->getAttributeSetName();

        // Get options
        $productOptions = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($product);


        foreach($productOptions['options'] as $key => $value){
            if( $value['label'] == 'Bunting Text' ){
                $text = $value['value'];
            }
        }

        if( $attributeSetName == 'Bunting' || $attributeSetName == 'bunting' ){

            $characterPrice = 1.50;
            $textLength = strlen($text);
            $customPrice = $characterPrice * $textLength;

            $quote_item->setCustomPrice($customPrice);
            $quote_item->setOriginalCustomPrice($customPrice);

        }
        elseif( $attributeSetName == 'Default' ) {
            // Check if the price is 0, if it is then override it.
            $currentPrice = $product->getPrice();

            if( $currentPrice == 0 ){
                // Don't really know
                Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost();

                // Set final price
                $finalPrice = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('finalprice_cust');
                $keepsakesPrice = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('finalprice_keeps');

                $quote_item->setCustomPrice($finalPrice);
                $quote_item->setOriginalCustomPrice($finalPrice);

                // Additional Options

                $additionalOptions = array(
                    'options' => array(
                         'label' => 'Finish',
                         'value' => Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('finish')
                    ),
                    array(
                         'label' => 'Size',
                         'value' => Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('size')
                    ),
                    array(
                         'label' => 'Printed On',
                         'value' => Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('printedon')
                    )
                );

                $quote_item->addOption(new Varien_Object(
                    array(
                        'product' => $quote_item->getProduct(),
                        'code' => 'additional_options',
                        'value' => serialize($additionalOptions)
                    )
                ));

            }
        }
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify "product edit screen"? Which route?